# BizTalk Design patterns

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

I am very new to BizTalk. I have been asked to create a application in BizTalk. I am facing some design level challenges.
Following are some of them:

1. Best approach in creating a project

   How to crate BizTalk solution. Means how to create projects. Do we need to create different projects for Maps/Orchestation/pipelines and references. Which is the best approach to develop a project?
2. Can we check in a BizTalk project in TFS

How multiple people can work on a single BizTalk solution? Can it be checked in in TFS and multiple people can take it and work on it? How merging will work?

3. Code review

Is there any way to review a BizTalk package? What are the best practices?

Comment: This question will probably be closed as it is 1) Too broad, containing multiple questions. 2) Primarily opinion based.    Both of which are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is very subjective.  I always establish that there is a 1-1-1 App/Solution/Deployment unit.  Meaning an Visual Studio Solution should be deployable/undeployable on it's own.  No references to other Solutions.

I do not create separate Projects for Schema/Maps/Orchestrations/Pipelines, there's no benefit unless the App/Solution is large...say more than 10 Message Types.  Then, it's OK to separate.

2. Yes, of course.  Any number of Devs can contribute to a Solution.  The only thing you can't do is Merge BizTalk Artifacts.  The Xml definitions are confusing to the Merge tool.
3. Code Review should be done just like any other project.